# Establish DDP connection over SSL to Meteor app

Tags: ssl, meteor, ddp

When a Meteor client uses `DDP.connect()` to connect to a DDP server, it's sent in plaintext. How can we establish SSL encrypted DDP connections?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor relays on SockJs, according to [SocksJs README](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client): `From SockJS' point of view there is nothing special about SSL/HTTPS. Connecting between unencrypted and encrypted sites should work just fine.`

My code:

```
var connection = DDP.connect("ws://127.0.0.1:3000");
```

If you switch from `ws` to `wss` (WebSocket Secure), if the host supports ssl, it will be used. In my localhost, I don't ssl installed and It doesn't fallback to ´ws´, you've to manually code it if you want so.